# Incorrect result of Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, bugs

`Maximize` is a well done command of Mathematica. However, there are spots on the Sun too. Trying in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[x*y]/(z + 1) + Sqrt[y*z]/(x + 1) + Sqrt[x*z]/(y + 1), 
1/(x + 1) + 1/(y + 1) + 1/(z + 1) == 2 && x > 0 && y > 0 &&z > 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

, I obtain (in a dozen  minutes) a warning

> Maximize::wksol:Warning:there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied;a result on the boundary will be returned.

which is OK and

> `Sqrt[2], {x -> -1, y -> 0, z -> -1}}`

which is not correct.
The change of variables `{x->r^2,y->s^2,z->t^2}` does not help and produces another incorrect result.

```
Maximize[{r*s/(t^2 + 1) + t*s/(r^2 + 1) + r*t/(s^2+1), 
1/(r^2 + 1) + 1/(s^2 + 1) + 1/(t^2 + 1) == 2 && r > 0 && s > 0 && t > 0}, {r, s, t}]
```

> `{\[Infinity], {r -> Indeterminate, s -> Indeterminate,  t -> Indeterminate}}`

and the same warning. The `NMaximize` command produces

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[x*y]/(z + 1) + Sqrt[y*z]/(x + 1) + Sqrt[x*z]/(y + 1), 
1/(x + 1) + 1/(y + 1) + 1/(z + 1) == 2 && x > 0 && y > 0 &&z > 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{1.41417,{x->24842.9,y->0.0000201261,z->0.0000201261}}`

without any warning.

The question arises: what is a workaround?

Addition. Another example of such sort is

```
Minimize[{x/Sqrt[1 - x^2] + y/Sqrt[1 - y^2] + z/Sqrt[1 - z^2], 
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && {x, y, z} >= 0 && {x, y, z} < 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

where Mathematica is running without any response for  a long time.

Comment: There is a typo, `r*t/(s^+1)` should be `r*t/(s^2+1)`.

Comment: Your first `Maximize` returns `{Sqrt[2], {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> ComplexInfinity}}` in Mathematica v12.2 , which seems to be correct!

Comment: I tried to solve this problem in Wolfram Alpha. One of the results is the same as yours. The Maximize function also works extremely slowly in my version. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize+Sqrt%5Bx*y%5D%2F%28z+%2B+1%29+%2B+Sqrt%5By*z%5D%2F%28x+%2B+1%29+%2B+Sqrt%5Bx*z%5D%2F%28y+%2B+1%29+on+1%2F%28x+%2B+1%29+%2B+1%2F%28y+%2B+1%29+%2B+1%2F%28z+%2B+1%29+%3D%3D+2%2Cx%3E0%2Cy%3E0%2Cz%3E0)

Comment: @user293787: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Thank you for your valuable comment. Therefore, we deal with a regression.

Comment: If I run your rst-code, I get `{Sqrt[2],{r->0,s->0,t->Indeterminate}}` in V12.3. Maybe you can check again what you get in V13.1, after correcting the typo.

Comment: @user293787: That was a typo in copy&paste.  I repeated the execution several times obtaining the same result `{\[Infinity], {r -> Indeterminate, s -> Indeterminate,  t -> Indeterminate}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround, done in the Cloud

Maximize isn't realy good with square roots. Get rid of them.

```
$Version

cond1 = {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0};

f = 
 Sqrt[x*y]/(z + 1) + Sqrt[y*z]/(x + 1) + 
    Sqrt[x*z]/(y + 1) /. {x -> a^2, y -> b^2, z -> c^2} // 
  Simplify[#, cond1] &;

cond2 = {1/(x + 1) + 1/(y + 1) + 1/(z + 1) == 2} /. {x -> a^2, 
    y -> b^2, z -> c^2};

(max = Maximize[{f, Join[cond1, cond2]}, {a, b, c}]) // AbsoluteTiming

13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)

Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.  >>

 {0.378328,{Sqrt[2],{a->0,b->0,c->Indeterminate}}}
```

Get an impression of the three equivalent maxima

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Sqrt[x*y]/(z + 1) + Sqrt[y*z]/(x + 1) + Sqrt[x*z]/(y + 1) == 
  Sqrt[2] - .01, {x, 0, 25}, {y, 0, 25}, {z, 0, 25}, 
 ContourStyle -> Red, FaceGrids -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works in 13.1 on Windows 10 too. It's still unclear to me why `Maximize[{r*s/(t^2 + 1) + t*s/(r^2 + 1) + r*t/(s^2+1),  1/(r^2 + 1) + 1/(s^2 + 1) + 1/(t^2 + 1) == 2 && r > 0 && s > 0 && t > 0}, {r, s, t}]` produced an incorrect result on a fresh kernel in  today's morning.

Comment: @user64494, dont't know. This (with r,s,t) works also well in the cloud with 13.1 for Linux.

Comment: `Sqrt[2]` is not a maximum of the objective function under the restrictions, but its supremum which is not attained and Mathematica says it.

Comment: I know this, not neccesary to mention.